# How to print a formatted string of 2D array matrices next to each other

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, formatting

I'm given a string and had it converted into a 2D array.
The string given was `*23**23412341_3*`

The code I wrote to convert it into a 2D array was:

```
public String[][] str2arr(String str)
{
    String[] rows = str.split("(?<=\\G....)"); // split the string at every 4th character
    String[][] matrix = new String[rows.length][];
    int r = 0;
    for (String row : rows)
    {
        matrix[r++] = row.split("(?<=\\G.)"); // split each of the string of each row
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

This code gives a result like `[[*, 2, 3, *], [*, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, _, 3, *]]`

And I have it formatted to

```
*23*
*234
1234
1_3*
```

using this code:

```
public void printMatrix(String[][] x)
{
    for (int i=0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<x[0].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(x[i][j] + "");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

But now I'm given a second string and needs to display it on the side of the matrix (its right), but not at the bottom of the first matrix.

```
*23* *23*
*234 *234
1234 1234
1_3* 1_3*
```

Is this possible? If not, why not and how can i update this code so I could achieve my target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do what you're asking. But you could instead, print both matrices again, side by side.

Create a class that holds all your matrices. This will assume all matrices have the same dimensions:

```
public class MatrixHolder {
    private List<String[][]> matrices = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addMatrix(String[][] matrix) {
        matrices.add(matrix);
    }

    public void printMatirces() {
        for(int i = 0; i < matrices.get(0).length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < matrices.size(); j++) {
                System.out.print(rowString(matrices.get(j)[i]) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static String rowString(String[] row) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String s : row)
            sb.append(s);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
String input = "*23**23412341_3*";

MatrixHolder mh = new MatrixHolder();
mh.addMatrix(str2arr(input));

mh.printMatirces();
System.out.println();

mh.addMatrix(str2arr(input));

mh.printMatirces();
```

Output:

```
*23* 
*234 
1234 
1_3* 

*23* *23* 
*234 *234 
1234 1234 
1_3* 1_3*
```

Comment: Brilliant. This allows not just 2 matrices but more than that, just what I needed for scalability of the program. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind String[][] x and then display binded xes.

```
public String[][] cbind(String[][] x1, String[][] x2) {


        String[][] output = new String[x1.length][x2[0].length +x2[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < x1[0].length; j++) {

                output[i][j] = x1[i][j];

            }

            for (int j = 0; j < x2[0].length; j++) {

                output[i][j + x1[0].length] = x2[i][j];
            }

        }

        return output;
    }
```